# How did 아프다 conjugate to 아파?

Tags: verb-endings, spoken-korean, verb

When conjugating the word `아프다`, how did we drop the vowel before `다(-da)` and add the `아 (-a)` to it?

**Is it a normal conjugation rule for verbs?**

E.g. in the sentence

```
하네요 여기가 아파.
I'm just saying, it hurts here.
```

`아프다` is conjugated as `아파`. **Is it a morphology rule or is it just a contraction for spoken Korean?**

It looks like the conjugated form is fairly common when it comes at the end of the sentence and ends with a `-yo`, from [Naver](http://endic.naver.com/search.nhn?sLn=kr&searchOption=all&query=%EC%95%84%ED%8C%8C):

```
다리가 아파요.  
My legs hurt.

발목이 아파요.  
My ankle hurts.

허리가 아파요.  
I have some back pain.

난 마음이 아파요.  
I'm broken-hearted.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All verbs will show up in the dictionary with 다 at the end of them.  This is referred to as the "dictionary form".  The dictionary form must be conjugated for use outside the dictionary (*but stand by, cause DVs have the easiest conjugation possible*).

---

### AV  (Action Verbs 동작동사)

Action verbs must be conjugated, at the very least, with ㄴ/는 as follows *(of course other conjugations 먹어, 먹어요, 먹습니다 still exist but aren't currently relevant to understanding this concept)*:

> 먹다 => 먹는다! (*Subject* eat/eats!)
>
> 하다 => 한다! (*Subject* do/does!)
>
> 읽다 => 읽는다! (*Subject* read/reads!)

---

### DV (Descriptive Verbs 형용사)

Descriptive verbs can be used directly in their dictionary form:

> 예쁘다 => 예쁘다! (*Subject* is/am/are pretty!)
>
> 좋다 => 좋다! (*Subject* is/am/are good!)
>
> 쉽다 => 쉽다! (*Subject* is/am/are easy!)

---

This is not to say that other conjugations of DV are impossible: 예뻐, 예뻐요, 예쁩니다, 좋아, 좋아요, 좋습니다 and the like are perfectly fine, too.  It seems like your question is primarily on the 다 which hopefully is now clear.

---

Now let me point out something else about what happens when you drop the 다. Verb conjugations may require 아/어 as they conjugate...so **how do you know if it's 아 or 어?** I'm glad you asked.

1. If a verb ends in 아 or 어, do not add 아/어

> 가다 => 가! or 가요! (go!)

2. If a verb's final syllable contains a dark vowel sound add 어

> 치다 => 쳐! (note the 이 combines with the 어) (kick!)
>
> 읽다 => 읽어! or 읽어요! (read!)

2. If a verb's final syllable contains a light vowel sound add 아

> 좋다 => 좋아! or 좋아요! (good!)
>
> 아프다 => 아파! or 아파요! (ow!)

---

And then of course 하다 is unfortunately irregular for adding 아/어:

> 하다 (adds 어 and when 아 + 어 combine they make 애) => 해! or 해요! (do *it*!)

And there are many other irregular verbs, for instance "ㅂ verbs" and "르 verbs".

In ㅂ verbs the ㅂ becomes 우 which is dark so you add 어:

> 쉽다 => (쉬 + 우 + 어) 숴워! or 쉬워요! (easy!)

In 르 verbs the ㅡ (으) is dropped and an extra ㄹ goes into the previous syllable and since ㅡ (으) is considered (*in this case*) light we add 아:

> 빠르다 => (빠 + ㄹ + ㄹ + 아) 빨라! or 빨라요! (fast!)

---

*"But I heard someone say 아퍼, what gives?"*

It's not uncommon for native Koreans to use a dark sound where a light sound should have been.  While 아파 is the 표준어 (standard/correct language), 아퍼 is quite common, ain't it?